# Execute a script from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline that builds a java artifact,
copies it to a directory and then attempts to execute a external script.

I am using this syntax within the pipeline script to execute the external script

```
dir('/opt/script-directory') {
    sh './run.sh'
}
```

The script is just a simple docker build script, but the build will fail
with this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /opt/script-directory@tmp/durable-ae56483c
```

The error is confusing because the script does not create any directories. It is just building a docker image and placing the freshly built java artifact in that image.

If I create a different job in jenkins that executes the external script as 
its only build step and then call that job from my pipeline script using this syntax:

```
build 'docker test build'
```

everything works fine, the script executes within the other job and the pipeline
continues as expected.

Is this the only way to execute a script that is external to the workspace?

What am I doing wrong with my attempt at executing the script from within
the pipeline script?

Comment: dir('/tmp') {
    sh '/opt/script-directory/run.sh'
} --- does that work?

Comment: It is not the script creating files.  (I guess)Jenkins is storing recovery information here

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure what it is doing at all. I changed the script to simply echo and it fails with the same error.

Comment: One a side note, have you tried "Pipeline speed/durability override" --> "Performance- optimized". As far as I understand this mode shouldn't store any information to disk, thus might do as a workaround.

Comment: This being a`docker build` script, simply granting Jenkins user read and exec permissions to the script file would not be sufficient: the user must be also added to the `docker` group, since root/sudo is required to run `docker build` scripts. If the user is not added, then builds may still work purely by chance if the two users have the same ID (which is often used to grant access to host paths to internal docker container users).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that the jenkins user (or whatever the user is that runs the Jenkins slave process) does not have write permission on `/opt` and the `sh` step wants to create the `script-directory@tmp/durable-ae56483c` sub-directory there.

Either remove the `dir` block and use the absolute path to the script:

```
sh '/opt/script-directory/run.sh'
```

or give write permission to jenkins user to folder `/opt` (not preferred for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in Jenkins, `durable` directories are meant to store recovery information e.g. before executing an external script using `sh`.
For now all you can do is make sure that `/opt/script-directory` has `+r` `+w` and `+x` set for jenkins user.

Another workaround would be not to change the current directory, just execute `sh` with it:

```
sh '/opt/script-directory/run.sh'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar concern when trying to execute a script in a Jenkins pipeline using a `Jenkinsfile`.

I was trying to run a script `restart_rb.sh` with `sudo`.

To run it I specified the present working directory (`$PWD`):

```
sh 'sudo sh $PWD/restart_rb.sh'
```