# how do I create Master + PR branch and run some tests on it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-api

I am new to jenkins. 
I want to build pipeline/jenkins job where once developer has pull request approved by other developers with 1 LGTM, I would build a new Master + the PR as new Master and run smoke tests.
If it passes, I will merge to the Master.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup a [multibranch pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) on a dedicate repo.

That dedicated repo would be one where (master+PR) branches are pushed to: their new branch would trigger the multibranch pipeline.

In order to push such branches (master+PR), you need another job which will:

- periodically fetch from the origina repo
- check for any PR branch with a +1 LGTM
- create a new branch from master and merge that PR branch
- push the resulting new branch to the dedicated remote repo mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks!how do I check for check for any PR branch with a +1 LGTM?

Comment: I am not using Gerrit.

Comment: @mtess Then you need to query those PR, filtering by state (for all the ones with state "approved"): https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests

Comment: I have created multibranch pipeline job. where do I check for step 2. PR branch with a LGTM?

Comment: @mtess one approach would be for your job to do the query I mention and exit if the branch which triggered the Jenkins job is not one of the PR branches with an "approved" state, as returned by said API GitHub query.

Comment: how do I achieve it using jenkinsfile if its possible?

Comment: @mtess First achieve it through a shell script. Then it is easy to encapsulate that script in a Jenkinsfile, caling said script in a bat/sh step.

Comment: I am doing it for first time. is there any sample documentation I can read up or sample jenkinsfile example? Thanks!

Comment: Sure: official documentation is https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/. For instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/38945443/6309. The idea remains that you can first make your script work independently of any Jenkins, *then* add that script to your source code repository, and make Jenkins use it through a Jenkinsfile step.

Comment: I don't see state "approved" for pull request : https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests any other way to find out approved pull request?

Comment: @mtess tes, sorry, it was in https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request.

Comment: Thanks @VonC how do I use this api this as part of my code in shared library?

Comment: @mtess same as before: make a script, then wrap it in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks but I need some help with script as well. if any sample script to refer where to start.

Comment: @mtess Sure. It starts with a curl: https://gist.github.com/mmyoji/d6284d2efd6701daa8adeaa340dee335. More complex example: https://gist.github.com/andrelaszlo/2e96027b531f6b177e73bef7ab064fbf#file-fix_repos-sh-L77-L89. Another script example: https://gist.github.com/florinel-chis/6185656. Those are to be adapted to your specific case, but can serve as examples, to get you started.

Comment: I am trying to make script but not able to.Also how do I access pullRequest in the script. It is global variable but I am getting error for it.

Comment: That would be better adressed in a separate question, where you can show your script, and your error message.