# How can i check the uploaded file to github using jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

im new to jenkins. Iam having folders in my github repo and each folder having data.json and para.json file. Now whenever someone uploads folder consisting of data.json and param.json, i need to run python script that looks into uploaded data.json and para.json to check its schema(structure) if the structure doesnot matches it will notify error. I know this can be done in CI. How do i do that since im very new to CI/CD

Answer (score 0):

Executing a shell/python script from your pipeline will resolve your issue. Take a look at this related question for more information: [Execute a script from jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945443/execute-a-script-from-jenkins-pipeline/38950171)